# Edit Text Auto Calculate

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app which calculates concrete volume. I have 3 editText fields but I want one of those text fields to calculate from feet to inches automatically when the data is entered. To do that you simply divide whatever figure that's in the field by 12, but how do I write code to do that?

Here is my Java code:

```
public class Calculation extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button aButton;
    private TextView tvAnswer;
    private EditText input1, input2, input3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculation);

        tvAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.length);
        input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.width);
        input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.thickness);
        aButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        aButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Double inputt1 = input1.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Double.valueOf(input1.getText().toString());
        Double inputt2 = input2.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Double.valueOf(input2.getText().toString());
        Double inputt3 = input3.getText().toString().equals("") ? 0 : Double.valueOf(input3.getText().toString());

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:
       tvAnswer.setText(Double.toString(inputt1*inputt2*inputt3));
            break;
        default:
            break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want one of those text fields to calculate from feet to inches
>   automatically when the data is entered

What you need is `TextWatcher`

Example

```
 public TextWatcher mTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // do calculation here
            calculation();
        }
    };
```

In `onCreate` method, add this

```
input1.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and give feedback​

Answer (score 0):

You have to use TextWatcher to your editText.

```
input1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // Call method to calculate your value same way you do in onClick()
        }
    });
```